# UITableViewAutomaticDimension and multiline label issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this code for my table (_filters = UITableView)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // table data set here ...
    _filters.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
    _filters.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_filters reloadData];
}
```

I have multi line label within my custom cell. Some rows are single line, some rows multi lines. I am using constraints. It works good, but what is problem:

When I open the controller, table displays for a while old not properly sized cells layout, then after a while, the proper layout is displayed. Probably because table data are set in viewDidLoad, and then there is reload of table in viewDidAppear.

But:

1) If I remove reloadData from viewDidAppear, correct cells layout is not rendered (unless the table cells are scrolled out of screen)

2) If I put the code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear, same problem as above. Correct cells layout is not rendered.

So now I have correct cells layout rendered, but for like 1-2 sec I see old bad cells layout, so it looks ugly..

I tried to put everything of the following calls in cellForRowAtIndexPath, to have correct layout yet on initial load, but nothing worked..

```
//[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
//[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
//[cell setNeedsLayout];
//[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

Any solution? Thanks..

Problem is both on iOS8 / 9.

Comment: add this method and label line set to 0. func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Comment: Hi Chirag, it worked thank you! (The missing method fixed it)

Comment: @Chirag, add your comment as answer here, so people will find it as helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** as per the Chirag  comment, add this UITableViewDelegateMethod method

```
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      }
```

try to run and check. If not works then have the above method then try the below steps.

**2.Remove** the **preferred width/the explicit content width of the label** in Storyboard/XIB.

[image]

Credit goes to useyourloaf

Refer this tutorial:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells/

http://openradar.appspot.com/17799811

Example:
https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/tree/master/SelfSize

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I didn't even know there is some explicit width on storyboard. My label didn't have this checked, but thank you for your answer and information, I will remember it.

Comment: I hope that adding func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat { return UITableViewAutomaticDimension } and removing the explicit width if it exist for label will work for your question. I learnt something from your question. thanks man.